# How to assign two different certificate for two IIS website

Tags: certificate, iis

**Context**

I have two different web sites on IIS (Win Server 2016) both listening on 80 and 443 and in the bindings I separate them with host name:
one is blog.mydomain.com in the other I left the host name binding empty, to allow both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com server by that site. I also set for both 443 to a self signed certificate and all worked perfectly

- I could reach one site on mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com both http
  and https
- I could reach the other site on blog.mydomain.com  http and
  https

**Issue**

When the time of greening the browser address line come, I bought a Commodo certificate (not the wildcard) for blog.mydomain.com. I installed it successfully and blog.mydomain.com is trusted green now...

However when I change the bindings for the site of blog.mydomain.com to use the Commodo certificate instead of the selfissued, the other site's binding also change (IIS manager give me a message, see picture in the end of the post)

This forecast the issue, I can not buy an other Commodo (not wildcard) certificate for www.mydomain.com (includes mydomain.com) because I will not able to configure the two sites for two certificate.

**Question**

I know the professional solution would be to buy a wildcard certificate, but it is 10 times expensive than a not wildcard, so I thought I can accomplish the task with two different not wildcard certificate.

Am I missing something? What is the issue here, are the two certificate too similar?

Comment: Forgot to attach the picture?

Comment: Have you got `Require Server Name Indication` checked on both sites?

Comment: No, I have not checked "Require Server Name Indication". Should I?

Comment: @mt025: Thanks for asking. Now I tried, and for blog.mydomain.com I checked, then for the other site (where the binding have empty hostname) I can not, but setting here to the other certificate it works now. Thanks. In case you post it as an answer I can mark it.